# Can Vaatu merge with someone and master all four elements?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Just like Raava gives the holder masters of all four elements what does Vaatu give the holder?  Can they all master all four elements?

This would then create an anti-avatar.

Comment: maybe a dup https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43020/could-vaatus-release-create-a-second-avatar?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the focus of the [climax](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Falls) of Book Two: Spirit (that is to say, Season 2). [Vaatu](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Vaatu) merges with [Unalaq](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Unalaq) to form the [Dark Avatar](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Avatar).

[Raava](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Raava) does not actually give Avatars their abilities, but transfers Wan's Lion-Turtle-given abilities to the Avatar:

> Between the Harmonic Convergences of 9,829 BG and 171 AG, Raava was merged with Wan's spirit, living on as the Avatar Spirit.
>   She enabled the Avatar to contact a past life as well as provide a considerable boost of power in the Avatar State.

This also applies to Vaatu's merging:

> Unlike the Avatar, the Dark Avatar did not have the ability to bend all four bending arts, since Unalaq could only waterbend prior to his fusion with Vaatu, unlike Wan, who went to the lion turtles with Raava and received all four elements.

Vaatu, and Raava, do however greatly enhance the abilites of those they merge with:

> Despite this limitation, the Dark Avatar's bending potential could still be significantly augmented by a variation of the Avatar State, in which Vaatu provided Unalaq an energy surge which allowed him to accomplish great feats of waterbending, such as creating large waves capable of dispersing several battleships. In this state, Unalaq's eyes glowed orange-red, as opposed to the white glow visible when the Avatar enters the Avatar State. Due to being fully aware of his spiritual capabilities, Unalaq had full control over the Dark Avatar State and was able to trigger the mechanism whenever he found it appropriate to use.

Comment: "Raava does not actually give Avatars their abilities, but transfers Wan's Lion-Turtle-given abilities to the Avatar:"  I'm pretty sure but can't find the source that a human can only hold one avatar element at a time.